# Rust libraries: Visibility of types vs. ability to name said types

Tags: rust

I have a Rust workspace with a library and a binary that uses said library:

- Cargo.toml:

  ```ini
  [workspace]
  members = ["lib", "bin"]
  ```
- lib/Cargo.toml:

  ```ini
  [package]
  name = "lib"
  version = "0.1.0"
  edition = "2021"
  ```
- bin/Cargo.toml:

  ```ini
  [package]
  name = "bin"
  version = "0.1.0"
  edition = "2021"

  [dependencies]
  lib = { path = "../lib" }
  ```

In the library, I was lazy and did not care about distinguishing `pub` from `pub(crate)`. I thought I could fix this by only exporting the symbols a user would need via `pub use`:

- lib/foo.rs:

  ```rust
  pub struct Foo {}

  impl Foo {
      pub fn name(&self) -> &'static str {
          "Foo"
      }
  }
  ```
- lib/bar.rs:

  ```rust
  use crate::foo::Foo;

  pub fn baz() -> Foo {
      Foo{}
  }
  ```
- lib/lib.rs:

  ```rust
  mod foo;
  mod bar;

  pub use bar::baz;
  ```

Despite `foo::Foo` not being public, publicly exporting `baz` is allowed, which surprised me. I was even more surprised that using the returned object in the binary is actually possible:

- bin/main.rs:

  ```rust
  use lib::baz;

  fn main() {
      let my_foo = baz();
      println!("Hello, {}!", my_foo.name());
  }
  ```

  Output: "Hello, Foo!"

Now, I already know how to prevent this from happening: Distinguish `pub` from `pub(crate)` everywhere in my library.

However, I still have a few questions:

- *Why* is this allowed?
- If the crate type of "lib" is "dylib", will all public symbols be exported, regardless of whether they are in a non-public module? Or only those symbols which are exposed "indirectly", as in my example?
- Does the unintuitive state of `lib::foo::Foo` (public type that is part of the API/ABI, but cannot be named) have any practical purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this allowed?

Because `pub` items are exported. Period.

If part of their path is not exported (one of the modules they're inside), then they are *unnamable* (you cannot name them), but they still can be used if they're inferred, or if there is another way to name them (someone `pub use`s them).

> If the crate type of "lib" is "dylib", will all public symbols be exported, regardless of whether they are in a non-public module? Or only those symbols which are exposed "indirectly", as in my example?

A simple test shows it is exported.

> Does the unintuitive state of `lib::foo::Foo` (public type that is part of the API/ABI, but cannot be named) have any practical purpose?

Yes, the more common being sealing a trait.

If you want to have a trait which can be used but cannot be implemented, the most common way to do that is:

```
mod private {
    pub trait Sealed {}
    impl Sealed for MyType {}
}

pub trait MyTrait: private::Sealed { ... }
impl MyTrait for MyType { ... }
```

This way, the trait and its members can be used, but it cannot be implemented because it has `private::Sealed` as a supertrait so you need to implement it too, but you cannot do that because it is unnamable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

What I'm still wondering is: Could the compiler theoretically meet my naïve expectations without breaking legitimate use cases? Of course, that would require a more complicated implementation that diagnoses cases such as mine, where a public function returns a non-public type and the caller would have to know the object layout of said type.

In the case of your practical example, I don't see a reason why `private::Sealed` would necessarily have to be exported from the shared library, but I have to admit I didn't think about it too hard.